# Search in a two-dimensional array

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to find the values in different points of the array. When I run the code, it always goes to `The value doesn't exists`, also I  do not know how to count the values that are same `r`.

```
    r = 0 
    c = txtbbus.Text
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        For j = 0 To n - 1
            If a(i, j) = c Then
                txtbres.Text = "The value exists " & r & " and it's in the position (" & i & ", " & j & ") "
            Else
                txtbres.Text = "The value doesn't exists"
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
```

And this is how I initialize `a`:

```
    txtbmatriz.Text = ""
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        For j = 0 To n - 1
            a(i, j) = CInt((100 * Rnd()) + 1)
            txtbmatriz.Text += a(i, j) & " "
            m += a(i, j)
            l += 1
        Next j
        txtbmatriz.Text += vbCrLf
    Next i
```

Comment: Don't use `Randomize` and `Rnd` to generate random numbers. You're not writing VB6 code. use the .NET `Random` class.

Comment: Don't use `Integer` and `String` like `If a(i, j) = c Then`. If you had `Option Strict On` that would be a syntax error. VB.NET is a much stronger language when you use `Option Strict On`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    r = 0
    c = txtbbus.Text
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim FoundMatch As Boolean = False

    For i = 0 To n - 1
        For j = 0 To n - 1
            If a(i, j) = c Then
                FoundMatch = True

                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If FoundMatch = True Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If FoundMatch = True Then
        txtbres.Text = "The value exists " & r & " and it's in the position (" & i & ", " & j & ") "
    Else
        txtbres.Text = "The value doesn't exists"
    End If
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is almost certainly that you don't break out of the loop when you find a match. Your code will only ever show you the result of the last element in the array because you always keep searching to the last element. Once you find a match, there's no point to looking further and, in fact, doing so is detrimental. Once you find a match, stop looking.

Finding a single/first match:

```vb
Dim rng As New Random
Dim matrix = New Integer(9, 9) {}

For i = 0 To matrix.GetUpperBound(0)
    For j = 0 To matrix.GetUpperBound(1)
        matrix(i, j) = rng.Next(1, 101)
    Next
Next

Dim target = rng.Next(1, 101)
Dim message As String

For i = 0 To matrix.GetUpperBound(0)
    For j = 0 To matrix.GetUpperBound(1)
        If matrix(i, j) = target Then
            message = $"{target} found at ({i},{j})"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If message IsNot Nothing Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Console.WriteLine(If(message, $"{target} not found"))
```

Finding all matches:

```vb
Dim rng As New Random
Dim matrix = New Integer(9, 9) {}

For i = 0 To matrix.GetUpperBound(0)
    For j = 0 To matrix.GetUpperBound(1)
        matrix(i, j) = rng.Next(1, 101)
    Next
Next

Dim target = rng.Next(1, 101)
Dim matches As New List(Of String)

For i = 0 To matrix.GetUpperBound(0)
    For j = 0 To matrix.GetUpperBound(1)
        If matrix(i, j) = target Then
            matches.Add($"({i},{j})")
        End If
    Next
Next

Console.WriteLine(If(matches.Any(),
                     $"{target} found at {String.Join(", ", matches)}",
                     $"{target} not found"))
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to find all the elements that are the same, and count them

Comment: @SantiagoantonioRomeroCiriac, and my edit provides code that demonstrates that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume `c = txtbbus.Text` is from some form input. Meaning a string. For the equality check you'd be testing against an Int type. Try casting the input from `txtbbus.Text` as an integer. Also, like the other poster said breaking from the loop on finding your match would also be a good decision.

Comment: I trully am fried, i declared "c" as integer at the top and I just saved the text of txtbbus in c, does that make it string?